# C# Control a Menu strip in a form from a usercontrol in the form

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls

I have a windows form application the has a Form(form1) a menustrip(menustrip1) and a usercontrol(usercontrol1). I have the code written that loads the user control into the form like this.
    `UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
    UC.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Clear();
    UC.Controls.Add(menuStrip1);
    this.Controls.Add(UC);`

Then when the UC is loaded I want to add menu items and handle their events. The problem is when I use this code to add Items it doesn't work but doesn't error out. Am I doing it wrong or can I simply not interact with the menustrip in this manner.

`menuStrip1.Items.Remove(fileToolStripMenuItem);
ToolStripMenuItem Save = new ToolStripMenuItem("Save", null,             saveToolStripMenuItem_Click);
fileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(Save);`

Comment: Have you tried accessing the menustrip through the Controls collection?  If you fill the name property, you can use that as the index.

Comment: Is the problem that "File" and "File->Save" are missing from the menu strip?  When you remove `fileToolStripMenuItem` from the menu strip it's not going to show up on the menustrip, nor will the save button that's added to `fileToolStripMenuItem`.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by access it through the controls collection. I thought I was accessing the control by calling the menustrip.item and manipulating it that way. Forgive my ignorance I have no formal training with any language.

Comment: No File remains there and the save is not. I believe I left in the remove in there after testing to see if it came out. It does not. It acts like I am interacting with it and the compiler sees it as a valid statement but at runtime it would appear to do nothing.

Comment: I think you're creating/using these controls in an odd way.  Why does `UserControl1` need to access the `menuStrip`?  What is your form doing with the `menuStrip` and what is `UserControl1` doing with it?

Comment: I agree with gunnerone, the call to `Remove()` doesn't make sense when you add a menu to that removed item a couple lines later.  Please show more complete code so we can understand what is happening...

Comment: @gunnerone the form is simply a form that has a menustrip. The user clicks menu strip items and then there is an event that loads the users control as you see in my post. the user control is what has a databinding source and other items for the user to interact with. what my intent was to pass the menu strip to the usercontrol to add a save button that when the user saves I can update the binding source in the user control. I know it is a little unusual as I haven't seen it anywhere else but I am not sure how else to keep consistency.

Comment: @Idle_Mind that is the code. they are in events. The first block is in a toolstripitem click event handler and the second is in the user control load event handler. ignore the remove that was a test to see if it actually removed the item.

Comment: It would be better for the menustrip to only be accessed by the form.  Then the user clicks the save button, have that handler (in `Form1`) call a function on the `UserControl` to update the binding source.

Comment: Update. When accessing the menustrip1 I was actually accessing the menu strip that was created in the user control and not deleted. So I guess the question that remains is on form1 the menustrip1 control was added to the usercontrol how can i interact with it from within the usercontrol to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do.  Form1 contains a menustrip, when you click a button it adds a new UserControl to the form.  Should the UserControl have its own menustrip?  Or are you trying to add a new button to the Form1 menustrip and have it call a function in UserControl when clicked?  Does UserControl1 do anything else with the menustrip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally disagree with your approach...

Assuming "menuStrip1" was dropped on the main form and had that **exact** name,  when you add it to your UserControl you can access it "by name" like this in the Load() event:

```
    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuStrip menu = this.Controls["menuStrip1"] as MenuStrip;

        ToolStripMenuItem File = new ToolStripMenuItem("File", null, fileToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        menu.Items.Add(File);
        ToolStripMenuItem Save = new ToolStripMenuItem("Save", null, saveToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        File.DropDownItems.Add(Save);
    }
```

*Also is there a way to add to the existing file that comes in with the tool strip menu or do i have to start it from scratch?*

Assuming "File" was placed on the main menu already and named exactly "fileToolStripMenuItem", this would be done quite similarly to the already accepted code above.  Instead of accessing `this.Controls()`, however, we'd access `menu.Items()` like this:

```
        MenuStrip menu = this.Controls["menuStrip1"] as MenuStrip;
        ToolStripMenuItem File = menu.Items["fileToolStripMenuItem"] as ToolStripMenuItem;

        ToolStripMenuItem Save = new ToolStripMenuItem("Save", null, saveToolStripMenuItem_Click);
        File.DropDownItems.Add(Save);
```

Comment: I did the above and that is what I was looking for. The question is when you program would you do it this way.

Comment: Also is there a way to add to the existing file that comes in with the tool strip menu or do i have to start it from scratch?

Comment: I got that probably the same time you were posting. I like this way better because it is a cleaner way to keep everything together. I am now using this two work with two user controls at the same time. This was my ultimate goal to be able to work with multiple controls with in one control. Are you a teacher? Your way of explaining things lead me in the right direction. I love that you gave me code but you explain things well.

Comment: Glad the code was helpful.  I'm not a teacher, I've just been answering questions in public forums for a looong time.  My handle is also [Idle_Mind](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/Idle_Mind.html)  over at Experts-Exchange where I started answering questions back in 2003.  I'm currently [#18](https://www.experts-exchange.com/hallOfFame.jsp) over there.  Long, verbose answers (and full blown articles) are less frowned upon over at EE.  Here at SO the answers tend to be shorter and more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Gunnerone had it. Keep the menu strip and all events in the form. add menu items related to the specific user control at menustripclick. In the UC call define a public method for the action and just call it from the form. This was simple, I keep overthinking this.